# when i create a react app, it has a error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The environment has been set up for using Node.js 18.17.1 (x64) and npm.

```
C:\Users\PC>npx create-react-app demo
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-13T04_58_29_291Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\PC>
```

can you help me?